# Client request get stuck when server is down

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have a client that does a simple request to a server. It usually works fine, but if the server is down or it simply doesn't exist, the request get stuck and does nothing else.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        # do things for initilization    
    
    def do_request(self):
        request_url = 'http://fhksdjhfksdhfk.com'
        try:
            response = requests.post(request_url, timeout=5)
            print('Response received from registration:', response) <-- Never reach this statement
            if response.status_code != 200:
                print('Request error at', request_url, 'error:', response.reason)
            else:
                print('Request finished successfully')
        except Timeout:
            print('Request timeout')
```

Any clue?

Comment: Is the indentation of the except clause ok?

Comment: Yes, the indentation is ok, it was wrong in the question when I copied it. If my server is up & running the code works well, I mean, it carries on.